# How to create directory with HTML button and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mkdir

I wanted to share with you my little attempt at code .. I basically have to make sure that once you press the button is created a folder (via mkdir and php) I do not want to be redirected to other php pages .. he simply has to create this folder, launch the alert and then he has to reappear as before ...
it's possible ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    function createDirectory()
 {
  $addettoSicurezza = $_POST["addettoSicurezza"];
  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  chdir("../../../../../Archivio/Cantieri");
  opendir(".");
  mkdir("../../../../Archivio/Cantieri/".$date."_".$nomeCantiere);
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Done!');</script>";
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<?php
     if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
?>
        <form action="" method="post">
          <p> 
    
 <table> 
 <tr>
    <td style=" border-style: none;"></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">2</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD" style="font-weight: bold">Addetto sicurezza</td>
 <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" style="width: 220px;" class="form-control" name="addettoSicurezza" id="addettoSicurezza" /></td>
    <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#CDECFD">Mail</td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"><input type="text" style="align:center;" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" name="mailAffidataria" id="mailAffidataria" /></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CDECFD"colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Crea directory" /> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
  
          </p>      
        </form>
<?php 
     }
     else{
       createDirectory();
    }
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can do this with ajax.

Comment: how? would you be so kind to link me?
@RainDev

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your 'createDirectory' function as follows

function createDirectory()
    {
        $addettoSicurezza = $_POST["addettoSicurezza"];
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');
        $date = date('Y-m-d');
        chdir("../../../../../Archivio/Cantieri");          mkdir($date."_".$addettoSicurezza);
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Done!');</script>";
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer .. but it does not work .. when I press the button I get a white screen and not my table .. and I do not even create the folder ..

Comment: That is because of the script. please make sure that the path on chdir is correct. otherwise change it to  chdir("Archivio"). for this you have to create folder Archivio on your root.